# Velocity increases

Tags: c++, sfml

When I move my object around its starts really slow and then begins to accelerate. I want a constant velocity but I have no idea what is wrong

```
    const float m_Walkspeed = 0.1;

    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left) && m_position.x > 0)
    {
        m_velocity.x -= m_Walkspeed;
        CurrentAnimation = &AnimationLeft;
    }

    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right) && m_position.x < 800) 
    {
        m_velocity.x += m_Walkspeed;
        CurrentAnimation = &AnimationRight;
    }

    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up) && m_position.y > 0) 
    {
        m_velocity.y -= m_Walkspeed;
        CurrentAnimation = &AnimationUp;
    }

    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down) && m_position.y < 560) 
    {
        m_velocity.y += m_Walkspeed;
        CurrentAnimation = &AnimationDown;
    }

    m_position += m_velocity;
    m_velocity = sf::Vector2f(0, 0);
    CurrentAnimation->setPosition(m_position);
}
```

Comment: I assume this is your game update function.  Is this function being called at regular intervals?  If it's not you'll need to find the time since the function was last and scale the position change appropriately.

Comment: Do you mean it increases in speed if you hold down a key?

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that you call this code at each frame, you have to consider the *time since last frame*:

```
m_velocity += timeSinceLastFrame;
m_position += m_velocity;
```